# WPF Dispatcher Operations Leak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dispatcher

I'm seeing a memory leak in our WPF application. In using .NET Memory Profiler, I can see that even after closing a window, the DataContext and UI elements are all sticking around because of Action delegates that are in DispatcherOperations in the Dispatcher queue...but have a ContextIdle priority and never seem to get processed.

Can I force the Dispatcher queue to flush when my Window gets closed?

Comment: Who is queuing the operations with `ContextIdle` priority? And why? Wouldn't it be better to fix *that*?

Comment: A third party component - namely Telerik

Comment: And you've contacted them about the issue?

Comment: Yes, with no useful reply, other than "that shouldn't happen and we can't reproduce". I can't reproduce either with a really simple dummy app, and they want a standalone reproduction before considering the issue further.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to include a synchronous call to a dummy method using dispatcher.Invoke with priority ContextIdle in the Window.Closing event. This should stop the UI thread from generating more dispatcher items, and should return only after the last ContextIdle items are processed. However, I couldn't verify that since without the Telerik component ContextIdle items get processed before the window closes, anyway.

I could also imagine that those items run in a loop, i.e. create themselves anew during their execution. In that case, it might help to set the DataContext explicitly to null before you close the window. This might signal to the components that they can stop their loop, and at least you won't leak instances of your datacontext objects this way.